# EOL is lost after parsing with Xerces

Tags: xerces

eol chars are substituted by white spaces by xerces parser in attribute value

```
<prolog>
    <metadata name="my_name" value="my 
value"/>
  </prolog>
```

Is there any way i can keep eol?

Answer (score 1):

found it  <strike>`$#10;`</strike> `&#10;` is doing the work, the xerces parser translates it automaticly into new line char.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the text be inside a CDATA if you want chars like an EOL?

Comment: thank you, but it does not work, parser wont recognize value of "value" inside cdata block as valid.